# How to get preg_replace() to delete text between two tags?

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace

I'm trying to make a function in PHP that can delete code within two tags from all .js file within one folder and all its subfolders. So far everything works except `preg_replace()`. This is my code:

```
<?php

deleteRealtimeTester('test');

function deleteRealtimeTester($folder_path)
{
    foreach (glob($folder_path . '/*.js') as $file) 
    {
        $string = file_get_contents($file); 

        $string = preg_replace('#//RealtimeTesterStart(.*?)//RealtimeTesterEnd#', 'test2', $string);

        $file_open = fopen($file, 'wb');
        fwrite($file_open, $string);
        fclose($file_open);
    }

    $subfolders = array_filter(glob($folder_path . '/*'), 'is_dir');

    if (sizeof($subfolders) > 0)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($subfolders); $i++)
        {
            echo $subfolders[$i];
            deleteRealtimeTester($subfolders[$i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}

?>
```

As mentioned I want to delete everything inside these tags and the tags themselve:

```
//RealtimeTesterStart

//RealtimeTesterEnd
```

It is important that the tags contains the forward slashes and also that if a file contains multiple of these tags, only code from `//RealtimeTesterStart` to `//RealtimeTesterEnd` is deleted and not from `//RealtimeTesterEnd` to `//RealtimeTesterStart`.

I hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `//RealtimeTesterStart`, `//RealtimeTesterEnd` and the code in between are on different lines?  In PCRE `.` does NOT match newlines.  You need to use the `s` modifier ( and you don't need the `()` unless you need the captured text for the replacement):

```
#//RealtimeTesterStart.*?//RealtimeTesterEnd#s
```

Also, look at `GLOB_ONLYDIR` for `glob` instead of `array_filter`.  Also, also, maybe `file_put_contents` instead of `fopen` etc.

Maybe something like:

```
foreach (glob($folder_path . '/*.js') as $file) {
    $string = file_get_contents($file);
    $string = preg_replace('#//RealtimeTesterStart.*?//RealtimeTesterEnd#s', 'test2', $string);
    file_put_contents($file, $string);
}

foreach(glob($folder_path . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $subfolder) {
    deleteRealtimeTester($subfolder);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also change your regex to use the [\s\S] character set which can be used to match any character, including line breaks.

So have the following

```
preg_replace('#\/\/RealtimeTesterStart[\s\S]+\/\/RealtimeTesterEnd#', '', $string);
```

This would remove the contents of //RealtimeTesterStart to //RealtimeTesterEnd and the tags themselves.